# Can I make the Angular Compiler throw an error when a non-existing property is bound?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-compiler

Consider the following template:

```
<p>Hello, {{ name }}</p>
<button (click)="doLogin()">Login</button>
```

together with this TS-Class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Neither `name` nor `doLogin()` exist. Still it compiles and runs without error. Only when I try to click the button, I get the error message *doLogin is not a function* in the browser's console.

I do know, that this behaviour (errors on runtime) is mostly intended by Javascript. Nevertheless, I'd like to have as many errors shown as possible at compile time. Using Typescript does most of this work.

However, property bindings seem not to be evaluated at compile time. In my opinion, the Angular-Compiler should be capable of this. I tried setting [fulltemplatetypecheck](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#fulltemplatetypecheck) to true, but this didn't seem to do the trick. Tried it with `ng serve`, `ng build` and `ng build --prod`.

**Is there a way to detect non-existent property bindings while compiling? If not, is this an intended behaviour?**

I'm using Angular 5.2.0, Typescript 2.5.3 and Angular CLI 1.6.4

Comment: I assume you're trying this with `ng serve`?

Comment: Also with ng build and --prod. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature will be available on angular 6. Based on the [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19681).

> We have a new compiler setting called fullTemplateTypeCheck (see
>   https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler-cli/src/transformers/api.ts#L99)
>   which will reveal this error.
>
> This setting will become the default in Angular 6, and is highly
>   recommended. We didn't turn in on in Angular 5 to not break existing
>   users. I.e. the behavior you are seeing here is exactly what users saw
>   in Angular 4.

**Angular 6 Below**

You can USE [TS Lint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) to achieve this.
I have used [TS Lint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) with visual studio code to validate non-existent property bindings and methods.

> It wont stop you from compiling but still show a error.

TS Lint will validate `method,property` not found in the component

[image: Ts Lint showing error in visual studio code]

**The angular CLI still compile your code successfully.**

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use TSLint in my IDE, but we could add it to the build-process or git-hooks to prevent having broken code...

Comment: Have you added that to build-process ?

Comment: Not yet, will do. But I'm still curious if this also works on compile-time - an when it doesn't, if (and why) it is a design issue of the ng Compiler.

Comment: pls take a look at this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19681