# Angular ng build --prod not throwing errors in code (but Language Services does)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

We have a quite big Angular app - and by change I found an error in it the other day. Unfortunately *ng build --prod* does not throw any errors during compilation. I created a small example to reproduce it.

Here is a simple interface `TestInterface` and a component `AppComponent`. The interface has one property: `propertyExists`. The component has a public property `test` defined as `TestInterface`- and the constructor sets `propertyExists` to true. Simple enough.

```
export interface TestInterface {
  propertyExists: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  test: TestInterface;
  constructor() {
    this.test = {
      propertyExists: true
    };
  }
}
```

The template has two paragraphs displaying the `propertyExists` property and a `propertyDoesNotExist` property not defined in the interface. The last paragraph has an `*ngIf` condition.

```
<p>
  Property exists: {{ test.propertyExists }}
</p>
<p *ngIf="true">
  Property does not exist: {{ test.propertyDoesNotExist }}
</p>
```

If I build with *ng build --prod* the app is build nice and pretty - no errors or warnings or anything though we reference a non defined property.

If I remove the `*ngIf` condition from the template like

```
<p>
Property does not exist: {{ test.propertyDoesNotExist }}
</p>
```

and build again with *ng build --prod* the compilation stops and throws a

```
ERROR in src\app\app.component.html(5,7): : Property 'propertyDoesNotExist'
does not exist on type 'TestInterface'.
```

I have tried all kinds of tricks and strict mode - but results are the same. The weird thing is I use VS Code with the Angular Language Services extension - and it marks the line as an error:

[image: Capture of VS Code showing error correctly]

And with correct error

```
Identifier 'propertyDoesNotExist' is not defined. 'TestInterface' does not 
contain such a member(undefined)
```

Anyone with explanations/suggestions on solving this?

### Edit

My specific question was not too clear. The specific question was: Why does *ng build --prod* not throw the error in the template if `*ngIf=""` is set on the parent tag?

### Answer

From DrFreeze's edit comment I solved it by adding a angular compiler parameter in tsconfig.json:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
}
```

Documentation found here: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#fulltemplatetypecheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you're trying to reach is not defined in the interface. Your most simple solution is to use:

```
<p>
   Property does not exist: {{ !test.propertyExists }}
</p>
```

The other way around, if the two properties don't have any logical relation between each other, is to make a class that extends that interface

```
export class testClass implements TestInterface {
   constructor(public propertyExists: boolean){ }
}

export interface extendedInterface extends TestInterface {
    propertyDoesNotExist: boolean;
}

export class someClass extends testClass{
   propertyDoesNotExist: boolean;

   constructor(options: extendedInterface) { 
       super(options);
       this.propertyDoesNotExist = options.propertyDoesNotExist;
   }
}
```

**Edit:** Based on dmoore1181 comment if you use Angular below version 6 it can be this [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19681) . See [Can I make the Angular Compiler throw an error when a non-existing property is bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403124/3242048)

Comment: I am fairly sure the question is asking why the angular cli doesn't throw an error while building and that question author knows what the error is.

Comment: @dmoore1181 You are right - my question was not _how_ to solve it (we just deleted the propertyDoesNotExist - as it does not exist) - as much as _why_ the compiler does not throw errors. I've updated twith more specific question for future reference.

Comment: @DrFreeze your edit led me on the right track. I put the specific answer in my edit.

Answer (score -3):

add **propertyDoesNotExist** in interface

```
export interface TestInterface {
  propertyExists: boolean;
  propertyDoesNotExist : boolean;
}
```

after this do **ng build --prod** it works fine :)

Comment: I am fairly sure the question is asking why the angular cli doesn't throw an error while building and that question author knows what the error is